# Can't connect to some WiFi networks

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I've recently give my MacBook Pro 16' to a repair and after that I can't connect to some of my work WiFi networks. If I use my mobile as a hotspot, it works okay. Here's what I get at `/var/log/wifi.log` while trying to connect to WiFi network when it fails (after that it says "The network  could not be joined."):

```
Fri Feb  1 10:55:57.916 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Fri Feb  1 10:55:57.916 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 34:80:b3:f5:ac:4c
Fri Feb  1 10:55:57.927 <kernel> AirPort_BrcmNIC::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: 6
Fri Feb  1 10:55:57.960 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 3 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Fri Feb  1 10:55:57.960 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 78:4f:43:90:7f:ff
Fri Feb  1 10:55:57.960 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Fri Feb  1 10:55:58.075 <airportd[2541]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
Fri Feb  1 10:55:58.085 <airportd[2541]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
Fri Feb  1 10:55:58.398 <kernel> IO80211AssociationJoinSnapshot::captureRequestCallback Problem reported from corecapture
Fri Feb  1 10:56:01.913 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:01.931 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:01.931 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 00:00:00:00:00:00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:02.154 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 3 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Fri Feb  1 10:56:02.154 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 78:4f:43:90:7f:ff
Fri Feb  1 10:56:02.154 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.129 <kernel> IO80211AssociationJoinSnapshot::captureRequestCallback Problem reported from corecapture
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.136 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.136 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.136 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 00:00:00:00:00:00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.388 <kernel> Setting BTCoex Config: enable_2G:1, profile_2g:0, enable_5G:1, profile_5G:0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.493 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 3 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.493 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 78:4f:43:90:7f:ff
Fri Feb  1 10:56:06.493 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.427 <kernel> IO80211AssociationJoinSnapshot::captureRequestCallback Problem reported from corecapture
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.432 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.434 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.434 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 00:00:00:00:00:00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.649 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 3 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.649 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 78:4f:43:90:7f:ff
Fri Feb  1 10:56:10.649 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Fri Feb  1 10:56:11.063 <kernel> IO80211AssociationJoinSnapshot::captureRequestCallback Problem reported from corecapture
Fri Feb  1 10:56:14.936 <kernel> IO80211AssociationJoinSnapshot::captureRequestCallback Problem reported from corecapture
Fri Feb  1 10:56:14.942 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:14.942 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:14.942 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

To compare, here's the log when I connect successfully:

```
Fri Feb  1 10:56:26.911 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 5 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Fri Feb  1 10:56:26.912 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 78:4f:43:90:7f:ff
Fri Feb  1 10:56:26.912 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 113)
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 1 of 4
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> FULL RSN IE FOUND:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [00000000] 30 14 01 00 00 0F AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC 02 0C 00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> storeFullRSNIE: getAP_IE_LIST returned 0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> PMK:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [00000000] B4 57 D2 2D 95 E0 AC 38 79 5D 25 58 4B 4F C3 3E A8 AF 2C 8F 76 B7 C4 5B FF F6 13 5C EA 54
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [0000001E] 6B 6B
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> TPTK:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [00000000] ED 72 DD AE F4 D6 D8 F7 32 09 31 E7 E0 4B BD 42 7F 6D A8 18 48 AE B3 37 DE 0B 86 05 96 7F
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [0000001E] 2F 66 64 CC 5C 69 1A D8 00 09 70 4D FC 42 94 1F 76 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [0000003C] 00 00 00 00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> KEY MIC:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 [00000000] FD 91 09 D4 48 57 42 CE BC 0A 1B 25 00 B4 6E 1A
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.089 <kernel> process1of4: sending replyPacket 135 bytes
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 169)
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: decrypting key data
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 3 of 4
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> process3of4: Performing IE check.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> process3of4: sending replyPacket ( len = 113 ).
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.100 <kernel> process3of4: received pairwise GTK
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.102 <kernel> PTK Install Timer: Installing PTK
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.102 <kernel> PTK:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.102 [00000000] 64 CC 5C 69 1A D8 00 09 70 4D FC 42 94 1F 76 14
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.102 <kernel> PTK Install Timer: Installing GTK
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.103 <kernel> installGTK: setting cipher key (flags = 0x0)
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.103 <kernel> GTK-RSC:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.103 [00000000] 00 00 00 00 00 00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.103 <kernel> GTK:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.103 [00000000] CF F5 12 04 2C CB A8 99 8A 9E 55 EB 69 0B 60 6A
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.103 <kernel> installGTK: GTK installed
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.133 <airportd[2541]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.136 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.164 <airportd[2541]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
Fri Feb  1 10:56:27.226 <kernel> Setting BTCoex Config: enable_2G:1, profile_2g:0, enable_5G:1, profile_5G:0
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 145)
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: decrypting key data
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 1 of 2
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> installGTK: setting cipher key (flags = 0x0)
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> GTK-RSC:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 [00000000] 00 00 00 00 00 00
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> GTK:
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 [00000000] 22 C1 3D 32 B9 21 0E 09 3C A9 15 D8 81 92 2E A9
Fri Feb  1 10:56:28.160 <kernel> installGTK: GTK installed
```

If I run `networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 <network name> <network password>`, here's what I get (couldn't find anything for this error code on the network, that's why I'm posting here):

```
Failed to join network <network name>.
Error: -3912  The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error error -3912.)%
```

When I do the same for hotspot network, it exits without any output and connects successfully.

What can be the reason?

Comment: I'm getting this exact error. Were you able to find a description for that error code? I've hit a wall.

Comment: @Brandon same, I didn't manage to fix it so I'm using wired connection whenever possible